# I want to get multiple relations in typeorm, tell me please some ways to do it

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

```
const announcement = await this.announsRequestsRepo.findOne({
        where: { id },
        relations: {
          owner: true,
          category: true
        }
      })
```

I want to get the relations of category and more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two approaches: `query builder` or `find` method

***find***

```
const announcement = await this.announsRequestsRepo.findOne({
        relations: {
          owner: {
            friends: true
          },
          category: {
            subcategories: true
          }
        },
        where: { id }
})
```

***query builder***

```
return await this.announsRequestsRepo
      .createQueryBuilder('announcement')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('announcement.owner', 'owner')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('announcement.category', 'category')
```

and deep nest with query builder:

```
  return await this.announsRequestsRepo
          .createQueryBuilder('announcement')
          .innerJoinAndSelect('announcement.owner', 'owner')
          .leftJoinAndSelect('owner.friends', 'friends')
```

references:
find method: [enter link description here](https://typeorm.io/find-options)
query builder: [enter link description here](https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder#joining-relations)

Comment: :) if you want you can accept my answer